# How do you move the scroll bar of a div to a certain option in mat-selection-list?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to be able to have the scrollbar scroll to a specific option upon a click.  Now, I know how to do this in an inapproriate way, where I access a private member variable of MatListOption class, but of course that is the wrong way of doing it.  Is there another way?  Again the code below does work as intended, but of course it is the wrong way of doing it.

For the scss, the #container has a height and overflow-y: auto to get the scrollbar.

Property '_element' is private and only accessible within class 'MatListOption'.

```
@ViewChild('list') list: MatSelectionList;

  public taskTypeAreas: ITask[] = [
    {name: "Area 1"},
    {name: "Area 2"},
    ...
    {name: "Area 20"}
  ]


  public scrollToArea(area: string){
    const topPos = this.list.options.find(v => v.value === area)._element.nativeElement.offsetTop;
    document.getElementById("container").scrollTop = topPos - 10;
  }

<div id="container">
  <mat-selection-list #list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let tta of taskTypeAreas" [value]="tta.name">
      {{tta.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>
</div>

<div><button (click)="scrollToArea('Area 8')">Area</button></div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0-dfywbi?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I had to research this more and found a method called "_getHostElement()" where I can access a property of .offsetTop.  So the answer is below.  Barring a better solution I will accept my own answer if nothing better comes up.

```
  public scrollToArea(area: string){
    const topPos = this.list.options.find(v => v.value === area)._getHostElement().offsetTop;
    document.getElementById("container").scrollTop = topPos - 10;
 }
```